# Column doesn't show up in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add the column "Customer Name" but when I run the code, that category doesn't show up in the column. I checked the excel spreadsheet I'm sourcing from and it definitely exists there so I'm unsure why it's not included in the output:

[image: Example]

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is a link to the spreadsheet I'm working with:
https://files.catbox.moe/m6x7w0.xlsx

Comment: If you don't mind, perhaps you can also include sample data for us to try out? Thanks

Comment: Okay I added a link to include the spreadsheet that I'm using for the data

Comment: I have seen your file. The thing is, using sum will only be possible for numeric values. As you can see here `FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrameGroupBy.sum is deprecated. In a future version, numeric_only will default to False. Either specify numeric_only or select only columns which should be valid for the function.
  df[['Region','Customer Name','Sales','Profit']].groupby('Region').sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the sum of the sales and profit of the customers in every region, you can groupby both `region` and `customer name`.

```
df[['Region','Customer Name','Sales','Profit']].groupby(['Region','Customer Name']).sum().sort_values(['Region','Sales'])

                                Sales     Profit
Region  Customer Name                           
Central Roland Schwarz          0.556    -0.9452
        Toby Swindell           1.112    -1.8904
        Christopher Conant      1.248    -1.9344
        Dorris liebe            1.624    -4.4660
        Cari Schnelling         1.720    -2.8380
                              ...        ...
West    Karen Ferguson       7182.766   878.4390
        Jane Waco            7391.530  2073.2828
        Edward Hooks         7447.770   589.7548
        Ken Lonsdale         8472.394   426.6132
        Raymond Buch        14345.276  6807.0879

[2501 rows x 2 columns]
```